# Firebase Query Error in Swift3: Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I'm not sure how to fix this error. Can someone explain it?

```
Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
```

Here's my Query.

```
media24HourQuery.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in

        var newItems = [[String: AnyObject]]()

        for child in snapshot.children {
            let title = (child as AnyObject).value["title"] as? String
            let userID = (child as AnyObject).value["userID"] as? String
            let mediaID = (child as AnyObject).value["mediaID"] as? String
            let timestamp = (child as AnyObject).value["timestamp"] as? Double
```

edit: this doesn't work either (everything is nil)

```
        for _ in snapshot.children {

            let title  = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["title"] as? String
            let userID = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["userID"] as? String
            let mediaID = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["mediaID"] as? String
            let timestamp = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["timestamp"] as? Double
```

and if I do print (child), this is what I get:

```
    // print(child)
    Snap (XsUwNDQB3qPdjYFCOLzANmsjjpf1-1474144681) {
    mediaID = "XsUwNDQB3qPdjYFCOLzANmsjjpf1-1474144681";
    timestamp = 1474144681490;
    title = "outside sep 17";
    userID = XsUwNDQB3qPdjYFCOLzANmsjjpf1;
}
```

edit: solved it. this works:

```
            let snapDic = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        for child in snapDic! {
            print (child)

            let childDic = child.value as? NSDictionary

            let title  = childDic?["title"] as? String
            let userID = childDic?["userID"] as? String
            let mediaID = childDic?["mediaID"] as? String
            let timestamp = childDic?["timestamp"] as? Double
```

Comment: The answer in that solution does not work for me.

Comment: @markthrow were you able to find a solutions for this